# How do I stop the result from exceeding 25?

Tags: python

```
def multiplication_table(number):
    multiplier = 1
    while multiplier <= 5:
        result = ___ 
        if ___ :
            break
        print(str(number) + "x" + str(multiplier) + "=" + str(result))
        ___ += 1

multiplication_table(3) 

multiplication_table(5) 

multiplication_table(8)
```

I'm supposed to fill in the blanks.

```
def multiplication_table(number):
    multiplier = 1
    while multiplier <= 5:
        result = number * multiplier
        if multiplier > 5:
            break
        print(str(number) + "x" + str(multiplier) + "=" + str(result))
        multiplier += 1

multiplication_table(3) 

multiplication_table(5) 

multiplication_table(8)
```

when I run the program i get multiplication_table 's to run correctly but the 3rd one runs all 5 of number * multiplyer. I've tried a couple variations but they all ignore the input to stop at 25 so I'm inputting that to where it's not being read which I understand that problem:

```
def multiplication_table(number):
    multiplier = 1
    while multiplier <= 5:
        result = number * multiplier
        if multiplier > 5 and result >= 25:
            break
        print(str(number) + "x" + str(multiplier) + "=" + str(result))
        multiplier += 1

multiplication_table(3) 

multiplication_table(5) 

multiplication_table(8)
```

Or I'll get "No output" which i don't understand why:

```
def multiplication_table(number):
    multiplier = 1
    while multiplier <= 5:
        result = number * multiplier
        if result >= 25:
            break
        print(str(number) + "x" + str(multiplier) + "=" + str(result))
        multiplier += 1

multiplication_table(3) 

multiplication_table(5) 

multiplication_table(8)
```

Comment: It's supposed to end the loop if any of the equations exceed 25 so I should only have up to 3 multiplication tables for 8 as the input but it goes all the way to 5 tables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I want to preface my answer with the fact that your question is not perfectly clear. Before you provide any code snippets or any attempted solutions, you should first fully define the problem and explain what an acceptable answer entails. Anyway, I will address each of your three attempts:

1. You have chosen to break the loop `if multiplier > 5`. This will actually do nothing! Your while loop condition already guarantees that the loop will end if `multiplier` is not less than or equal to 5. Therefore, your `if` condition will never be true.
2. Your second break condition has the same issue as the first attempt. The left side of the `and` statement will never be true.
3. From what I can tell from your question, this answer seems the closest to being correct. This is the output I get when I run the third attempt:

   `3x1=3 3x2=6 3x3=9 3x4=12 3x5=15 5x1=5 5x2=10 5x3=15 5x4=20 8x1=8 8x2=16 8x3=24`

I believe you don't consider this to be the correct solution because the program skipped "5x5", which would **equal** and **not exceed** 25.

This occurred because your condition was to break `if result >= 25`.

The binary operator `>=` means greater than OR equal. "5x5" is 25 which is equal to 25, so the program broke out of the loop.

The operator you are looking for is `>`, which only means greater than.

Comment: hahaha woah I can't believe I was off by just that, but thank you so much for the help and tip on my question not making clear sense. I will try better next time. I really appreciate the help!

Comment: @NoahWright No problem! I'm glad I could help you out. Can you mark my answer as accepted?